# Android: How can I force a facebook auth by mobile web

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-authentication

I want to develop the android app with facebook authentication. But if the phone has facebook application in it, I cannot auth on my app, if not, it works well.

so, i want to force a facebook authentication by mobile web without facebook application.

Only if I use authorize(. , .)in application, it uses facebook app directly.

How can I fix this problem??

additionally, Hackbook(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/hackbook/) also doesn't work if I auth by facebook app. I cannot login on app.

/////comment

I found the answer by myself

Change the authorize function in facebook.java in facebook sdk.

```
public void authorize(Activity activity, final DialogListener listener) {
    authorize(activity, new String[] {}, FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,
            listener);
}

/**
 * Authorize method that grants custom permissions.
 *
 * See authorize() below for @params.
 */
public void authorize(Activity activity, String[] permissions,
        final DialogListener listener) {
    authorize(activity, permissions, FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, listener);
}
```

now it works!

Comment: Just for the record.  if anyone is trying to solve the somewhat infamous "Unity3D Facebook, hash is wrong" issue {the approach here is one solution}, there's now a solution: ttp://answers.unity3d.com/questions/609810/using-facebook-api-with-android-says-login-is-canc.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use Facebook SDK 3.0 and the login button the best way to force this is setting a LoginBehavior to the LoginButton. This can be done like this:

```
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
authButton.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```

Source: [Android - Force Facebook connexion - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467289/android-force-facebook-connexion)