# Android - Force Facebook connexion

Tags: android, facebook

I'm a french guy so please excuse my english !

I'm developping an App Android and I want to allow my users to connect us via Facebook.
BUT ! But, I want to "force" the code to use the facebook web and **not** to launch the facebook application !

Am I clear ? :)

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Also ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084372/android-how-can-i-force-a-facebook-auth-by-mobile-web

Answer (score 2):

Generally, it's not recommended to use ONLY the webview for login, so unless you have a very specific use case, you should always use SSO.

That said, you can disable SSO by passing in [SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/SessionLoginBehavior#SUPPRESS_SSO) to a [Session.OpenRequest](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Session.OpenRequest).

First, you need to familiarize yourself with the [Facebook SDK for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/android/). Make sure you go through the [Getting Started Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/), and then the [Using Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/) tutorial.

Following the tutorial, if you're using the LoginButton, then you can just call

```
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
authButton.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```

in your onCreateView() method.

Comment: I don't really understand... can you show me a link or a code ? I can't find it on the web :/

Comment: updated with some links to tutorials, and how to set up the button to use only web login.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to auto login for the user, then just fire an intent which starts the web browser and goes to the facebook login page.

Comment: Yes ! This is that I need !! Do you know how can I do that ? :/ Thanks :)

Comment: It's not that simple, because you need to intercept the response, and extract details in order for your app to connect to Facebook. Please see my updated answer above.

Comment: @Florian Mac Langlade See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004515/android-sending-an-intent-to-browser-to-open-specific-url