# Cant add android keyhash to facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I am having trouble adding my Android generated keyhash in the new facebook developer console.

My keyhash is:

```
5VGCq1JAhzR0Vvc/Yb8ZRbDQabc=
```

but when I add it to my app om facebook dev-site and save, it gets rewritten into:

```
5VGCq1JAhzR0Vvc%2FYb8ZRbDQabc%3D
```

I know it should work because I have other facebook apps (added before) with the same hash, and they (the Android app) work.

**Edit**

To be continued. Se my other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655147/android-hash-key-changes-in-facebook-app/20659292#20659292).

Comment: You need to escape the `/` and `=`

Comment: Your not the only one, i just had this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655147/android-hash-key-changes-in-facebook-app

Comment: What browser/OS version are you using?

Comment: Now this issue seems to have solved itself for me. Entered hashkeys no longer gets rewritten. Whether it is solved by fb-team or just required a computer restart from me I do not know.

Comment: i've created a tool for that, check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17732453/2226605
 up vote my answer if i helped you.